# Remove extra spaces and \n from Nokogiri result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

Parsing my existing HTML using `Nokogiri::HTML(existing_html)` and after performing some operations on it, Nokogiri returns this output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <p>["\n", "\n", "   </p>
      \n", "      
      <meta http-equiv='\"Content-Type\"' content='\"text/html;' charset='UTF-8\"'>
      \n", "      
      <title>My Html</title>
      \n", "   \n", "   \n", "      
      <div valign='\"top\"'>
      \n", "         
      <div class='\"myclass\"'>
         \n", "            
         <div class='\"content\"' style='\"white-space:' pre-wrap>\n", "               <img src="%5C%22MyImageSource%5C%22">\n", "           </div>
         \n", "      
      </div>
      \n", "   \n", ""]
   </body>
</html>
```

I wish to remove the extra space and '\n' characters. So suppose this is stored in the `result` variable, and I tried `result.to_s.gsub(/\n/, '')` and `result.to_s.gsub(/\n/, '').strip`, but am getting the same stuff back.

How do I remove the extra space and "\n"? Also I am curious to learn why it gets added?

Let me know if any code is needed to show how am I getting the result.

Comment: `result.to_s.gsub!`?

Comment: It's not clear precisely what data you're operating on, you have an array of text nodes, not a string. It doesn't "get added", it's what's in the html. Which is funky anyway since there's a meta tag in the body. You almost never want to work with the string representation of a parsed document anyway, it's not what the document is, it's the string output of each Nokogiri element node.

Comment: @orde - result.to_s.gsub!(/\n/, '') is still giving me the same output.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Thats what I am getting after I do Nokogiri::HTML(existing_html). The nodes comes back in an array. Am I not doing the parse right way? Sorry I am learning Nokogiri and this is just my sample project to learn.

Comment: Okay I realized what is going wrong here. The problem is not with Nokogiri, but the way I am collecting data inside 'existing_html' variable from the file which has original html. I was doing existing_html = (html_file.readlines()) and this was storing the data within an array. Doing Nokogiri::HTML(open(existing_file)) doesn't add any \n and extra spaces.

Comment: And that's exactly why you need to include the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem you're seeing. We have NO idea what you were doing, and can't help you unless you show us.